# Area Moment of Inertia about y axis of i Beam

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

I was wondering if anyone could give me some input on what I am doing wrong here, because it is driving me crazy. I am trying to calculate the area moment of inertia about the y axis of this I beam:

[image]

This is the solution:

[image]

And here is my solution:

$I_y=\Sigma[\bar I_{y_i}+A_id^2_{x_i}]=\frac{h_1t^3}{12}+2(\frac{b^3\tau}{12}+(b\tau)(.5h_1+.5\tau)=23926950 mm^4$

where $\tau=\frac{h_2-h_1}{2}=15mm$

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong here!

Comment: For $I_y$ all distances to centroids are zero since you can split this shape up to three rectangles. Top, middle and bottom. All three have centroids along the _y_ axis.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: Thank you for notifying me, Kanos. I skimmed through the posts you listed, and see that you are right. I would however like to say that I think these policies make me a little sad, as what are defined as homework questions, like mine, often arise from conceptual misunderstandings, like mine, and might be of help to others. I will try to not post more questions of this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the shape into three rectangles with centroids on the *y*-axis. This way there is no need to calculate the perpendicular offsets $d_i$ to the axis.

[image]

$$ I_y = \frac{h_1}{12} t^3 + 2 \left( \frac{\tau}{12} b^3 \right) $$

Comment: Except the $(b\tau)(.5h_1+.5\tau)$ term of the _op_ isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you, ja72. I understood from your answer how to solve these problems. I appreciate you taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the first and second line of the "solution" don't agree with each other.

The moment of inertia can be written as the sum of

1. The central section - length $t$, height $h_1$: $$I_c = \frac{1}{12} h_1\cdot t \cdot t^2$$
2. The end bars - length b, total height of the two = $(h_2 - h_1)$: $$I_e = \frac{1}{12} (h_2 - h_1) \cdot b \cdot b^2$$

This is not the expression they have in their first line - although the numerical evaluation on the second line is correct (agrees with the above).

I am struggling to understand what you are doing with your expression... why are you introducing $A_i$? Referencing everything to the axis of rotation, $A$ doesn't even come into it? I don't know if the above helps.